# Using require to use file with hash

Tags: ruby

I am trying to refer to a hash written in another file, and tried:

```
require './filewithhash' #this file has hash

puts name_hash['somename'] #just trying access by the index
```

and got undefined local variable or method error.

Comment: Always tag the question with the language you are using.

Comment: We need to see a small sample of the file you're trying to require. In theory it works but you're getting an error so something is wrong. Also, please read through the formatting documentation when you're creating a question. It helps make it a lot easier to read.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The language I'm using is Ruby 1.9 on Mac OSX 10.9.  The file I'm trying to require is a simple hash:code_words = {
  'starmonkeys' => 'Phil and Pete, those prickly chancellors of the New Reich',
  'catapult' => 'chucky go-go', 'firebomb' => 'Heat-Assisted Living',
  'Nigeria' => "Ny and Jerry's Dry Cleaning (with Donuts)",
  'Put the kabosh on' => 'Put the cable box on'
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that when requiring file in ruby, local variables are out of scope. Therefore **any** local variables defined in required file will be **not** available later on.

Solutions:

1. Make your program object oriented and add this hash as a field in some class
2. Make your variable constant (like this: `NAME_HASH`)
3. Make your variable global (like this: `$name_hash`)
4. Make your variable an instance variable (like this: `@name_hash`)

If program is very simple, I would choose option 3. However if it's suppose to grow, 1 is your best choice.

Answer (score 0):

Requires in Ruby don't just inline the file like in PHP; each file has its own scope. That is, the code in the file will execute in a scope that means that all local variables are all constrained to that file's scope, and will not be visible outside of it.

In order to execute a file in the current scope, you're going to have to eval it with the current binding:

```
file = "file_with_hash.rb"
File.open(file) {|f| eval f.read, binding, file }
```

This is a bad idea and you shouldn't do it unless you know what you're doing and why. Instead, you should expose that hash as a member of a constant (which transcends the file scope):

```
# foo.rb
module Foo
  PROGRAMMER_WORDS = {foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3}
  ...
end

# another file
require 'foo'
Foo::PROGRAMMER_WORDS # => {:foo=>1, :bar=>2, :baz=>3}
```